# React Hooks and Socket.IO compare values before update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I would like to know how can I compare the values of what I receive from socket with my value from state before updating.

So the socket will send me a new location every second but I would like to update the state only when the latitude or longitude has changed or every couple of seconds

Here is what I have now and the reason I don't want to use it like this is because the performance drops drastically by updating this every second

```
const [from, setFrom] = useState({})
const [to, setTo] = useState({})
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('locationUpdated', function (data) {
        const location_data = {
            pickUp: {
                lat: data.latitude,
                lng: data.longitude
            }
        }
        setFrom(location_data)
    })
    setLoaded(true)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for what you need in your function:

```
socket.on('locationUpdated', function (data) {
    // from.pickUp.lat - current latitude
    // from.pickUp.lng - current longitude
    // if at least one of them is different from what you just get - update
    if (from.pickUp.lat !== data.latitude || from.pickUp.lng !== data.longitude) {
        const location_data = {
            pickUp: {
                lat: data.latitude,
                lng: data.longitude
            }
        }
        setFrom(location_data)
    }
        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just check that the location data is different and only set it if it is?

```
   useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('locationUpdated', function (data) {
        const location_data = {
            pickUp: {
                lat: data.latitude,
                lng: data.longitude
            }
        }
        const {pickup: currentCoords} = from
        const {pickup: newCoords} = location_data

        if(currentCoords.lat != newCoords.lat || currentCoords.lng != newCoords.lng){
        setFrom(location_data)
        }
    })
    setLoaded(true)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

the function returned by useState() is actually provided an argument - so setFrom() for example, is more accurately setFrom((prevState) => { ...etc...etc return etc}).  You can easily compare to prevState; if no change or update is needed return prevState - React will not re-render under those conditions.  Be careful on your compare between your location_data and prevState - they are different *objects*, so a simple "===" test is not likely to be enough.